# python - what is an efficient way to traverse a list of coordinates in reverse

Tags: python, list

I have a current list that contains points of a path from origin and destination 
this is from a 3x3 matrix and a starting position of 2,2 and ending position of 0,0

The grid also have cells that are not traversible at position:
    0,1
    0,2
    1,1

So the grid looks like this:

```
            -----------------
            |Goal| Wall| Wall |
            ==================
            |    |Wall |      |
            ===================
            |    |     | Start|
            ===================
```

After running an algorithm to get an optimal path , I was able to get the possible ways to get from 2,2 to 0,0

```
PathCaptured:      ['2,2,1,2,2.0', '2,2,2,1,2.0', '2,1,1,0,5.0', '2,1,2,0,4.0', '1,0,0,0,7.0']
```

So the structure is represented as : [startposx,startposy,destx,desty, score]

I was hoping to use the path in reverse to reconstruct the points.

The problem I have is I am creating 2 for-loops to traverse the list to make sure that I connect the two points to come up with the answer of

```
[[2,2][2,1][1,0][0,0]]
```

Is there an easier way to do this in python?

UPDATED with current code:

```
        first_time=True
        for i, e in reversed(list(enumerate(self.action_list))):

            if debug:
                print i, e
            if first_time:
                startx,starty,destx,desty,_ = e.split(",")
                ctr += 1
                box_path[ctr] = [destx, desty]
                ctr += 1
                box_path[ctr] = [startx,starty]
                #box_path.append([destx,desty])
                #box_path.append([startx,starty])
                first_time = False

            else:
                for j in range(len(self.action_list)):
                    dx, dy, dx_1, dy_1,_= self.action_list[j].split(",")
                    Dx,Dy = box_path[ctr]
                    if (Dx == dx_1 and Dy == dy_1):
                        box_path[ctr+1] = [dx,dy]
                        ctr += 1
                        #box_path.append([dx,dy])
                        break
            if debug:
                print box_path
```

Comment: Sounds like you want to create a dictionary of the form `{(startx, starty): [(destx1, desty1, score1), (destx2, desty2, score2), ...], ...}`

Comment: i updated with how i do it but i do not think it is efficient since ultimately i need to interrogate the output as a series of steps from start to goal ..